# How to run logwatch and tell to email me manually?

Tags: email, logwatch

I am running

```
/usr/sbin/logwatch
```

and it prints it output to `stdout`. Why if `MailTo` parameter is set in config file.

If I do

/usr/sbin/logwatch --mailto MYEMAIL

it works, but why? What is the purpose of `MailTo` config parameter then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose that `MailTo` parameter is set on the configuration file is to serve for the daemon itself, for example to send log reports periodically.